# Shorthand of compiling min and max values from an array with object into new object

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to acomplish what I want:

I do have an array with object like that:

```
let data = [
  {val1: [1,2,3,4], val2:[6,7,8,9] }
]
```

What I want is an object like:

```
let limit = {
  minX: 1, maxX: 4, minY: 6, maxY: 9
};
```

My Code works but once more I'm wondering if there is a nicer and shorter way to achieve it? Here is my solution:

```
  determineMinxMax(data: any) {
    let limit = {minX: null, maxX: null, minY: null, maxY: null}
    limit.minX = Math.min(...data.map(item => Math.min(...item.val1)));
    limit.maxX = Math.max(...data.map(item => Math.max(...item.val1)));
    limit.minY = Math.min(...data.map(item => Math.min(...item.val2)));
    limit.maxY = Math.max(...data.map(item => Math.max(...item.val2)));
    return limit;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code looks more like traditional JS, it does not benefit from typing features provided by the *TypeScript* language.

The solution I suggest below is not necessarily *shorter*, but its main goal is to put the things in order using the TS style.

First of all, interfaces can be created to define the structures of the `data` and `limit` objects:

```js
interface MyDataItem {
  val1: Array<number>;
  val2: Array<number>;
};

interface Limit {
  minX: number;
  maxX: number;
  minY: number;
  maxY: number;
};
```

To access the `val1` and `val2` properties generically, a type and respective constants can be defined:

```js
type PropertyAccessor = (item: MyDataItem) => Array<number>;

const accessorX: PropertyAccessor = item => item.val1;

const accessorY: PropertyAccessor = item => item.val2;
```

Similarly, to access the `min` and `max` values, we can define dedicated mapping constants:

```js
type ValueExtractor = (values: Array<number>) => number;

const extractorMin: ValueExtractor = values => Math.min(...values);

const extractorMax: ValueExtractor = values => Math.max(...values);
```

Now, the implementation of the `determineMinMax` function becomes very concise and does not include repetitive stuff:

```js
const determineMinMax = (data: Array<MyDataItem>): Limit => ({
  minX: extractMinMax(data, accessorX, extractorMin),
  maxX: extractMinMax(data, accessorX, extractorMax),
  minY: extractMinMax(data, accessorY, extractorMin),
  maxY: extractMinMax(data, accessorY, extractorMax)
});
```

Finally, we need to implement the `extractMinMax` function, which contains the main calculation logic:

```js
const extractMinMax = (data: Array<MyDataItem>, 
                       propertyAccessor: PropertyAccessor, 
                       minMaxExtractor: ValueExtractor): number =>
  data.map(propertyAccessor) ​// extract the array with the current property from data
     ​.map(minMaxExtractor)   // find the min value of each property
     ​.reduce((prev: number, next: number) => minMaxExtractor([prev, next])); // find the min value among all min values
```

...and a test case checking the calculated value:

```js
describe('Q268329', () => {

 ​it('should return expected value', () => {
   ​const data = [
     ​{val1: [1,2,3,4], val2:[6,7,8,9] }
   ​];
   ​const limit = determineMinMax(data);
   ​expect(limit).toEqual({
     ​minX: 1, maxX: 4, minY: 6, maxY: 9
   ​});
 ​});

});
```

Comment: I noticed you are consistently using `Array<T>`. I only have limited experience with TypeScript, but in my limited experience, it seems that `T[]` is a more idiomatic way to write that.

Comment: @"Jörg W Mittag" There is no "idiomatic" way between `Array` and `[]`, both are similar. It's simply a choice of coding style.